# Extracting CSV Header data type

Tags: c#, csv

In my current project, I am trying to derive the data type of CSV file. For instance, the following is the .CSV file.

```
sepallength,sepalwidth,petallength,petalwidth,class
6.2,2.8,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.9,3,4.2,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,3,4.2,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.2,Iris-virginica
```

My requirement is that a program should give me the following output.

- "sepallength" is of "float" datatype
- "sepalwidth" is of "float" datatype
- "petallength" is of "float" datatype
- "petalwidth" is of   "float" datatype
- "class" is of "String" datatype

I have written the following program. However the "`columnName.GetType()`" function always return **string** data type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadCSVFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This is a file Path that a user has to input.
            string csv_file_path = @"C:\TestCSV\iris.csv";
            string columnName;

            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

            Console.WriteLine("Column Value of the CSV file are as follows:");
            Console.WriteLine("=========================================");

            // This will retrieve columnNames from the table.
            foreach (DataColumn column in csvData.Columns)
            {
                columnName = column.ColumnName;
                Console.WriteLine(columnName);
                Console.WriteLine("Column type " + columnName.GetType());
            }
    }

    /*
     *  This function takes the file Path as an input and returns a Datatable.
    */

    private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            // Connect to the .CSV file Path
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

                // This will read the column name of a .CSV file.
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();

                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }

                // This code retrieves rows from the .CSV file.
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }

                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

Comment: Show the `GetDataTabletFromCSVFile` method as that is what is parsing file and determining the column type.

Comment: you could load all as strings, then attempt to parse as floats. If the full column converts to float then it "floats". If not then it is a string. would get more complicated for extra types

Comment: @Nkosi:Thanks for the pointer. Could you please advise which library you have used? Because, `GetDataTabletFromCSVFile` method is not popping up.

Comment: In your code example you are calling this method `GetDataTabletFromCSVFile` Which would mean that it is one of your methods. I didn't use any library, it your code. I'm asking to see what you did in that method to better understand your problem and hopefully provide you with a solution.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You read the data as a string array.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli : My question is  -- how can I extract the datatype of CSV header file.  I am expecting the output should be something like this: (1) "sepallength" is of "float" datatype (2) "sepalwidth" is of "float" datatype (3) "petallength" is of "float" datatype, (4) "petalwidth" is of "float" datatype,  (5) "class" is of "String" datatype.

Comment: you need to determine the type inside the string `str` with  `int.Parse(str)` and `float.Parse(str)`, depending on your needs, you need to do it before filling the Datarow or only instead of the GetType().

Comment: @FalcoAlexander: Thanks for the pointer. you  mean I should determine the type in the `GetDataTabletFromCSVFile()'  function, right?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli : I agree that I am reading the data in the string array with the function.  `string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields()`. What will be your suggestions? How should I read the data ? Any suggestions for the data structure that I should use?

Comment: yes, it would be the clean way to already get the datacolumns correctly typed for future use, if you want to calculate with the data

Comment: You cant determine the datatype from the header - they are always strings.  Do you really not know the datatypes being sent to you or is it simply that the order changes?

Comment: @Plutonix : Here - what I have done, combing the solution. I have extracted data type from the data row. I have stored datatype into one array, and then related with each column.

Comment: Swell, but whether you know the types or not, you are recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my example code:
(you cannot use it with .columnname as this is always a string, only the content of the columns are of different types:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string str = "6,2"; // float with decimals from europe
    Console.WriteLine(mytesttype(str).GetType());
    str = "6232";
    Console.WriteLine(mytesttype(str).GetType());
    str = "6String";
    Console.WriteLine(mytesttype(str).GetType());
}

static object mytesttype(string str) {

    int i;
    float f;
    if (int.TryParse(str,out i)) return i;
    if (float.TryParse(str, out f)) return f;
    return str;

}
```

Comment: Let me try with the solution in my code. Why somebody has given -1 to the answer. Any specific reason?

Comment: This program works good for the integer, but do not parsing float. While parsing to `float`, it is returning `system.single`. Any correction do we need?

Comment: Remember that `float` is an alias for the System.Single type! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used your solution. I have extracted data type from the data row. I have stored datatype into one array, and then related with each column